# Unable to login to gmail

Tags: android-management-api

I enrolled a device under work profile,  installed gmail app from playstore through android management API. I pre-configured email(through managed configuration). On device I can see the email but when I try to login(provided password) it says contact your admin.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you figure out what was happening? Also could you share the JSON of how you set the managed configuration for the same? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to the app log, you need to make "email_address", "exchange_username" and "exchange_host" all valid in managed configuration.